# In Perl,can we enter two values for the same key in a hash without losing(overwriting) first one?

Tags: perl, hash

after i declare a hash in perl

```
%hash1=(a=>"turkey",
        b=>"india",
        c=>"england",
        d=>"usa")
```

if i assign a new value to already existing key like

```
$hash1{d}="australia";
```

i am losing the previous value with key 'd' i.e "usa" because when i do

```
print %hash1;
```

i dont see the value "usa"...how to retain both the values for the same key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A hash key can only contain a single scalar value, so if that value is a string, you are stuck with one item per key.  However, there is nothing stopping you from storing array references (which are also scalars) as the value.  To make things easier, you should probably store only array references or strings, and not mix the two:

```
my %hash1 = (a=>"turkey", b=>"india", c=>"england", d=>"usa");

# upgrade all values to arrays
# $hash1{$_} = [$hash1{$_}] for keys %hash1;   # a way with `keys`
$_ = [$_] for values %hash1;  # a better way with `values`, thanks to ysth

push @{ $hash1{d} }, 'australia';

print "$_ : @{ $hash1{$_} }\n" for keys %hash;
```

Comment: `$_ = [$_] for values %hash1`

Comment: @ysth => nice, I forgot that unlike `keys` which returns copies, `values` returns a list of lvalues.

Answer (score 3):

As JohnSmith said, use a hash of array:

```
my %hash1 = (
    a => ["turkey"],
    b => ["india"],
    c => ["england"],
    d => ["usa"],
);
```

and use it as:

```
push @{$hash1{d}}, "australia";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to store a hash of lists

example:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1977

Comment: There's no such thing as a hash of lists.

Comment: @friedo language is flexible. It's reasonable that he means a hash that stores arrays instead of simple scalars as values.

Comment: @friedo: And just what is it that arrays *hold* if not lists, eh? Seems to me that having to always recite the full litany of “a hash of scalars holding references to arrays holding lists of scalars of unknown content type” is a mite wordy. It’s hard to be too hard on those who leave a few bits of that out in casual conversation. A “hash of arrays” is perfectly fine, as Perl has no other implementation of the same, and a “hash of lists” is but one step removed. Indeed, the same argument for relaxed speech applies there, as there is no other way to do it.

Comment: @frido, I disagree. JohnSmith's statement isn't wrong, it's just useless. It simply repeats Siddharth's question without suggesting how one would go about storing a list in a hash element. His link, on the other, shows how a reference to an array can be used to store that list.

Comment: @Axeman, yes, language is flexible, but in certain cases language must be precise. In programming we have very specific definitions for words that would otherwise be synonymous in everyday language. And in Perl particularly, arrays and lists are two very different things.

Comment: @tom, I agree that "hash of arrays" is fine, but "hash of lists" is not.

Answer (score 0):

This question is precisely equivalent to asking whether if we first assign a variable that can hold only one value some particular value, but then later assign that same variable a different value, whether we can ever access the earlier value that we've just now overwritten.

The same answer applies to both: no, of course not, not without changing around your storage class, access mechanism, or both. One means one. When you have come up with a mechanism that works for a simple unsubscripted scalar variable, you will have done so for an entire class of problem.